# MVC4 EF6 mapping parameters from form

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a problem with mapping the form data sent from a view into the model class it is designed for.

I have a Teacher model:

```
public class Teacher : Person
{
    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public String Title { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime DateOfApproval { get; set; }

    public ICollection<ThesisApplication> ManagerOf { get; set; }
}
```

and a ThesisApplication model( a student fill application form where he says who wants to be his manager ).

```
public class ThesisApplication
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual Thesis Thesis { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Manager")]
    public virtual int ManagerId { get; set; }
    public virtual Teacher Manager { get; set; }

    //other properties that doesn't matter here
}
```

and fluent API for the connection between them

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ThesisApplication>()
            .HasRequired( s => s.Manager ).WithMany(s => s.ManagerOf );
```

In my form I have:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor( x => x.ManagerId, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)( ViewBag.People  ) )
```

where

```
ViewBag.People = new SelectList(this.databaseEntities.Teachers.All(), "PersonId", "FirstName");
```

However when i pass the form to the create method in my controller like this

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create( ThesisApplication application )
{ ...
```

I got the right managerId but the Manager property is empty( null ). When trying to get property of Manager exception is thrown.

Can someone explain why this happens.
I'm interested in a solution without using the foreign key. Something like
DropDownFor( x => x.Manager ) to map the Manager property without using the foreign key.

Thanks:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The object you're seeing coming back from the form post is a plain object, instantiated outside of the Entity Framework, by the MVC model binder.  If you want to get the `Teacher` object being represented, you'll have to use the [DbSet.Find](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696418%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) method (or any other method from the `DbSet<Teacher>`):

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(ThesisApplication application )
{
    using(var context = new TeacherContext()) //or whatever/however you access your DbContext
    {
        var teacher = context.Teachers.Find(application.ManagerId);
    }
}
```